# text processing rows to columns for a block

Tags: text-processing, awk, solaris, csplit

I have a file containing lists on Solaris:

```
List A
hi
hello
hw r u

List B
Hi
Yes

List C
Hello
```

I need to transpose the lists as shown below:

```
List A    List B    List C
hi        Hi        Hello
hello     Yes
hw r u
```

How can I do this on Solaris?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU ***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ max=0 }
     /^List/{ if(k && k>max) { max=k; idx=c } ++c; k=0 }
     NF{ a[c][++k]=$0 }
     END{ 
         for(i=1;i<=max;i++) 
             for(j=1;j<=c;j++) printf "%s%s",a[j][i],(j==c)?ORS:"\t" 
     }' file | column -ts$'\t'
```

The output:

```
List A  List B  List C
hi      Hi      Hello
hello   Yes
hw r u
```

Comment: This is truncate the List B, List C columns if List A is lesser then B and C

Answer (score 3):

You could use `awk` to split each block into separate files, then `paste` them together (below is assuming always there is empty lines between each lists).

```
awk '/^$/ {N++;next}{print >"file"N}' infile.txt
paste file*
```

Also you can move the `paste` command into `awk`.

```
awk '/^$/ {N++;next}{print >"file"N} END{system("paste file*")}' inile.txt
```

The output is:

```
List A    List B    List C
hi        Hi        Hello
hello     Yes
hw r u
```

to having beauty indentation in result when varying lines length like below:

#### Input file:

```
list A
hi
hello
hw r u

List B
Hi this is list B
Yes

List C
Hello, this is list C
```

you can do [**`paste file* |column -s $'\t' -tn`**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392658/72456) and will have result:

```
list A  List B             List C
hi      Hi this is list B  Hello, this is list C
hello   Yes
hw r u
```

Comment: Instead of  `awk`, `csplit` might be more suitable as it is designed for file splitting on a pattern match. In this case match empty lines and delete the match pattern: `csplit -f file_ --suppress-matched infile.txt '/^$/' '{*}'` . ALSO: Note that the pasting via `paste file*` might be problematic when having `file1` and `file10`.

Answer (score 1):

[Besides of my previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390928/72456), there is also `csplit` command to split the file in that same way and then use `paste` command to get desired output.

```
csplit -zs -f outputfile inputfile '/^List/' '{*}'
paste outfile*
```

- `'/^List/'` is a pattern to match and break the file there into the next new file
- `'{*}'` repeat the pattern as many times as possible
- `-z` is used to remove empty output files; and `-s` is used to do not print counts of output file sizes
- `-f` is used to define custom prefix *outputfile##* where `##` is by default 2 digits, you can define it with `-n N` (N is number of digits in suffix after defined prefix)

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
for i in "List A" "List B" "List C"; do sed -n "/$i/,/^$/p" h.txt >"$i.txt"; done

paste List\ *
```

output

```
List A  List B  List C
hi  Hi  Hello
hello   Yes 
hw r u
```