# Print two files in two columns side-by-side

Tags: shell-script, command-line, scripting, text-formatting, paste

I want to output two text files in two columns — one on the left side and other one on the right.

`paste` doesn't solve the problem, because it only insert a character as delimiter, so if the first file has lines of different lengths output will be twisted:

```
$ cat file1
looooooooong line
line
$ cat file2
hello
world
$ paste file1 file2
looooooooong line   hello
line    world
```

If there was a command to add trailing spaces like `fmt --add-spaces --width 50` the problem would be solved<sup>(1)</sup>:

```
$ paste <(fmt --add-spaces --width 50 file1) file2
looooooooong line                                 hello
line                                              world
```

But I don't know a simple way to do this.

##### So how to merge files horizontally and print them to standard output without twisting?

In fact I just want to read them side-by-side.

---

<sup>(1) **UPD:** command to add trailing spaces does exist, e. g. `xargs -d '\n' printf '%-50s\n'`.
But running

`$ paste <(add-trailing-spaces file1) file2`
won't produce expected visual output when `file1` has fewer lines than `file2`.</sup>

Comment: You may use `awk` for your hypothetical `fmt` command, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394541/1741542 as an awk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about `paste file{1,2}| column -s $'\t' -tn`?

```
looooooooong line line  hello
line                    world
```

- This is telling `column` to use `Tab` as columns' separator where we takes it from the `paste` command which is the default seperator there if not specified; generally:

  `paste -d'X' file{1,2}| column -s $'X' -tn`

  where `X` means any single character. You need to choose the one which granted that won't be occur in your files.
- The `-t` option is used to determine the number of columns the input contains.
- This will not add long tab between two files while other answers does.
- ***this will work even if there was empty line(s) in file1 and it will not print second file in print area of file1***, see below input/ouput

  Input file1:

  ```
  looooooooong line

  line
  ```

  Input file2:

  ```
  hello
  world
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  looooooooong line  hello
                     world
  line
  ```

Comment: Generally `paste -d @ file1 file2 | column -t -n -s @` where `@` is any delimiter that is not contained in files.

Comment: @belkka exactly

Comment: I had been trying this but without the `$`.  This is the answer for me, but could you explain what the `$` is doing here?

Comment: @paradroid please see  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

Comment: I get  `-n requires an argument`. Isn't that used for naming the table?

Comment: @einpoklum my `column` command man page says _`-n      By default, the column command will merge multiple adjacent delimiters into a single delimiter when us‐
             ing the -t option; this option disables that behavior. This option is a Debian GNU/Linux extension.`_

Comment: @αғsнιη: And are you sure it's a good idea for your answer to require being on Debian? I mean, don't get me wrong, that's what I have at home,, but not all Linux/Unix systems are Debian. At least comment about this assumption in your answer.

Answer (score 12):

With single `pr` command:

```
pr -Tm file[12]
```

- `-T` (`--omit-pagination`) - omit page headers and trailers, eliminate any pagination by form feeds set in input files
- `-m` (`--merge`) - print all files in parallel, one in each column

Comment: What does the `-T` do?

Comment: This can truncate long lines without any warning, but I like it.

Comment: On my mac I had to use `pr -tm file[12]`. (minus `-t`)

Answer (score 1):

A portable solution:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -F'\t' '{ printf("%-30s %s\n", $1, $2) }'
looooooooong line              hello
line                           world
```

This uses `paste` to produce a tab-delimited input for `awk`.

The `awk` script simply takes the two tab-delimited fields and outputs them using `printf()`.  A column of 30 characters is reserved for the first file.  The `%-30s` means "30 positions of string data with left alignment". Removing the `-` would produce a column aligned to the right, and changing `30` would change the column width.

It also deals with uneven length files. Here I've added lines to the second file:

```
looooooooong line              hello
line                           world
                               hello
                               world
                               hello
                               world
```

And, when reversing the order of the files on the command line:

```
hello                          looooooooong line
world                          line
hello
world
hello
world
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
paste -d '\n' file1 file2 | xargs -d '\n' printf '%-30s  %-30s\n'
```

Inspired by [@Kusalananda's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392657).

<sup>Note: The `-d` parameter of `xargs` is only available on GNU version, but not on BSD.</sup>