# Script to copy lines under specific heading and create new text file from original log.txt

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a log.txt file which contains 20k lines. Each line  having numbers and there xyz plane coordinates and they are separated by sets. Sets can be identify by there names as ABC_1, ABC_2 and so on in the log.txt

From this log.txt file I want to segregate all sets data in to individual Text files, which should contain all data from set  (eg. ABC_1).

My log.txt looks like below.

```
ABC_1: 
1, (xyz coordinates)
2, (xyz coordinates)
3, (xyz coordinates)

 .... Continue
ABC_2: 
101, (xyz coordinates)
102, (xyz coordinates)
103, (xyz coordinates)

 .... Continue
ABC_3: 
201, (xyz coordinates)
202, (xyz coordinates)
203, (xyz coordinates)

.... Continue
ABC_99: 
9991, (xyz coordinates)
9992, (xyz coordinates)
9993, (xyz coordinates)

.... Continue
```

I want to create a script which can give me 99 individual text files from a single log.txt file and which should be named as set name `ABC_1.TXT`, `ABC_2.TXT` ... to `ABC_99.TXT` from log.txt.

Comment: I assume (?) you want the contents of new files to be the intervening lines? Or empty files?

Comment: With duch questions you should always provide both example input and example output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text processing rows to columns for a block](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390918/text-processing-rows-to-columns-for-a-block)

Comment: what else you need more than just `awk '/^ABC_/{N++;next} {print >"ABC_"N".txt"}' infile` (assuming the bocks are sorted with `#` in `ABC_#` otherwise `awk -F: '/^ABC_/{fname=$1".txt";next} {print >fname}' infile` ) and that you can find in the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390928/72456) in flagged question except you no need paste them which you can ignore it?

Answer (score 2):

With csplit

```
csplit -s -b %d.txt -f ABC_ Log.txt /ABC_/ {*}
```

Comment: you need `-z` option to remove empty file(s) thought.

Comment: @αғsнιη yes and no. this way we get a empty file ABC_0.txt and we can remove it. with -z ABC_0.txt contain ABC_1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^ABC_/{
         if (fn) close(fn); sub(":", "", $1);
         fn = $1".txt"; next
    }
    { print > fn }' Log.txt
```